# How to apply stroke to textblock in xaml under uwp 10 app

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10

I want to apply a black stroke on a white textblock in uwp app like the one shown in the picture below

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually called outlined text. The easiest way is find a specific outline font and apply it for the FontFamily property of the TextBlock control.

For example, you could download the font file '.ttf' and put it in the 'Assets' folder.

```
<TextBlock FontSize="42" Text="Hello World" FontFamily="Assets/your outlined font.ttf#font name"/>
```

[image]

Another way is using Win2D relevant APIs to render outlined text.

You could refer to the [Win2D-ExampleGallery](https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D-Samples/blob/master/ExampleGallery/)'s TextOutlines sample for more details.

Comment: Thanx for the answer